# What "bad loser" means in this context?

Tags: vocabulary

Here is an example given in the Cambridge dictionary for **bad**:

She's just a bad loser (= she is unpleasant when she loses).

Why does bad go back to "she" instead of "loser"? I would translate this sentence as "she loses very bad" meaning she loses with the worst result possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would be right, *if* the sentence worked in the same way as

"She's an exceptionally good cook."

But to be a "bad loser" is an **idiom**.

> If someone is a good loser, they accept that they have lost a game or
>   contest without complaining. If someone is a bad loser, they hate
>   losing and complain about it.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/good-loser-bad-loser

Comment: Worth noting that "sore loser" is a common synonym.

Answer (score 0):

I think the implication is that when she loses, her behaviour as a consequence of the loss is considered to be bad.  It's not about the size or scope of the loss itself.

Comment: Exactly: It is the loser's reaction/behaviour/attitude that is bad.